How to make text spaced from the text that was above it?
I want to make the next sentence in my HTML code a bit spaced from the top text, but I don't want to use <br> every single time. This is what I've tried:


<blockquote id="tomFrom">
  "You don't make moral choices based on the outcome.<br> You make them based on whether they're right or not."
  <footer><cite>-Tom. From</cite></footer>
</blockquote>



I tried to use margin spacing but I'm just not sure what's the most efficient way.

You want to space every line apart, or every sentence, or just the first line or sentence from the next?

Use the line-height property from the CSS.
you can set it by px, em, %, whatever suits your project.
Or if they are different tags, just use padding-top.
Here's an example:


blockquote {
  line-height: 30px;
}
<blockquote id="tomFrom">
  "You don't make moral choices based on the outcome.<br> You make them based on whether they're right or not."
  <footer><cite>-Tom. From</cite></footer>
</blockquote>




line-height is for readability of the line and current element and not for pushing other elements away. The same is true for padding. This is what margin is for.
